# Finding obstacles between 2 objects in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

My Idea is to identify whether there are any obstacles between the two objects

now this obstacles could be other objects too.

for example there are 2 doors I need to find if there are any object such as table,chairs between them.

also the direction of checking the obstacles should be towards the target.

adding more to my idea can I do this above things using dbid of objects
so If I provide dbids of 2 object is there any way I would get other object which are in there way.

I have also tried to explain this in this [image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [example](https://github.com/cyrillef/forgefader) which does something similar, but your case is a bit more tricky. In this example, I use a [THREE.Raycaster](https://github.com/cyrillef/forgefader/blob/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewing.Extension.Fader/Viewing.Extension.Fader.Core.js#L483) from PointA to PointB and find/count all object between these 2 points.

This approach is quick and good enough for a point to point aspect. The complexity with your question is to determine blocking objects of various shape which can partially block the view; if partially blocking the view, you can still see some vertices of the final objects, but not all. This is more a HLR, or raytracing approach and that takes a lot of time to calculate. The THREE.Raycaster can help since you can still pass a mesh as parameter, but that will be a very slow process even if you are using the BVH tree from the viewer to eliminates some meshes from the process.

An alternative would be to write a custom shader to use the GPU to do the math for you, and that will be much faster. Unfortunately, I do not have such example ready. If the point to point approach is good enough, the code below should help.

The code extension of my example is located [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/forgefader/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewing.Extension.Fader)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example application named [ForgeFader](https://github.com/jeremytammik/forgefader) that uses ray casting to determine the number of walls between two points in a RVT model, both using the Revit desktop API and `three.js` in the Forge viewer.